# Interface As Service In Interface Based Programming :How To Implement A Service Provider Class Against Its Client Using Interface

Tags: c#, programming-languages, interface

First Of all ,I Hope To choose a good Title For my Question.

according to The chapter 7 Of "The Essential C#" book That Tries to Describe The Interface Concept
a wall plug Is an Interface and  all of appliances ***(Clients)***
that want to recieve AC power must implement this interface.Ok This 
makes me to ask some simple questions.

1-In our Domain there is an entity called Socket that is the Power Supplier and
in other words is ***The Service Provider***,what is the relation
between this Service provider and The Service(Interface),and how we must 
implement The Socket Class.?Could anyone Give a sample Implementation of Socket Class Or Give Some Advices 
Or Sample Source Code ?Thank u all.

2-If we look at Interface as Contract Or Specification
We Find that Sometimes it needs to consider some Constant values in our
contact (or specification) and others should not Change and Modify these items 
and should Follow them exactly .such as The PinsDistance and The PinsLength In our Domain,
 But we know its not possible in C# to Use
Constant in an interface (in Java Its possible) How You handle This issue.

A Sample implementationn Of This Issue are provided here.

```
interface I2PinsWallPlug
{
    void Plug();
    void Unplug();

    //***** Its Not Allowed To Use Const In an Interface In C# *****
       //const int Pinsdistance = 1;
       //const int PinsLength=5;
    //***** Its Not Allowed To Use Const In an Interface In C# *****
}

// A sample appliance is As a Client And Must Implemnt The Interface To Recieve Power 
class MyAppliance : I2PinsWallPlug
{
    public void Plug()
    {
       //...
    }

    public void Unplug()
    {
        //...
    }


}

//The Socket Class is Our Service Provider In Here and 
//I dont know My implementation Is Right Or Not ?????????????
class Socket
{
    public Socket( I2PinsWallPlug twoPinsWallPlug)
    { 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Client not only gets the interface of the service but entities as well. There are cases where your in/out parameters are purely basic .NET types but most other cases, these are complex types and need to be provided to the client.

If you do not have such entity, you may perhaps create a constants class and provide it to clients - *and that is what I have done just a few days ago.*

---

Example of a class for constants

```
public static class SystemConstants
{

    public static readonly string Foo= "BAR";
    public static readonly int[] ValidTypeIdsForBaaz = new int[]{290,291};

}
```

---

**UPDATE - Question 1**

Depends what we mean by service. Service are usually logical and sometimes physical as well. A logical service lives in the same process boundary while abstracted by its clients and a physical service sits in a another process on the same machine or another machine as a web service, WCF service or ...

Without knowing more about your domain model - what this service actually does -  it is not possible to come up with abstractions. Provide some info on the Socket and we should be able to help with abstractions.

Comment: There you go. I am using static readonly instead of constants so that if it changes then it is updated without recompile.

Comment: it seems that u answered my second question but what about my first question could u please give a sample code for Socket class .and about your response i think technically its right ,but conceptually when we discuss Interface as contract we expected that it woulb be possible to provide a complete package to clients and they would be  forced to fulfil all of its items and it seems interface in c# doesnot Cover The Contract Concept completely,thanks

Comment: According To This ViewPoint Id like To See The Problem Simple,So Lets Assume The Socket is a Logical Service provider that stayed on a Same machin with client.thank u so much.

Comment: Siamak jan, this is not really enough for coming up with a proper abstraction of your model. What does Socket do? Describe in a paragraph and we can come up wit a few things. Perhaps in a new question, just post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

how about using an abstract base class rather than an interface

```
public abstract class I2PinsWallPlug
{
    protected const int Pinsdistance = 1;
    protected const int PinsLength = 5;

    public abstract void Plug();
    public abstract void Unplug();
}

public class MyAppliance : I2PinsWallPlug
{
    public override void Plug()
    {

    }

    public override void Unplug()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ok ,So this proves that at least  calling interface in C# is not correct ,an what about my first question,thanks

Comment: Update:ok ,So this proves that at least calling interface as Contract in C# is not correct becouse itsnot completely support The Contract Concept am i rght?,an what about my first question,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The notion of interface in C# is closer to what it should be, cause interfaces have nothing to do with implementations and shouldn't contain any data or impl.

"**Inheritance Is Not Subtyping**

**Perhaps the most common confusion surrounding object-oriented languages is the difference between subtyping and inheritance. The simplest distinction between subtyping and inheritance is this: Subtyping is a relation on interfaces, inheritance is a relation on implementations**"

**Ref: Software Engineering - Cambridge University Press - Concepts in Programming Languages**